# Is it possible to purge azure cdn endpoint using storage key?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-cdn

I want to create a function which will purge a file on Azure CDN.
[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cdn/endpoints/purgecontent) in the documentation It says How can I purge the content specifying the path.

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/{profileName}/endpoints/{endpointName}/purge?api-version=2017-10-12
```

But the security is provided by Azure Active Directory OAuth2 Flow.
Hence I need to use `clientId`, `secretId` (from here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/maheshk/2017/04/01/azure-cdn-how-to-purge-cdn-content-from-c-code/)

```
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/microsoft.onmicrosoft.com");
            ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
            Task<AuthenticationResult> resultstr = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", clientCredential);

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            //authentication using the Azure AD application
            var token = resultstr.Result.AccessToken;
```

I wander Is there a way to make purge request using storage key and not `clientId`, `secretId`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The Azure Rest API [`Endpoints - Purge Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cdn/endpoints/purgecontent) is integrated with Azure AD authentication, it needs your valid credentials to get the access token.

See this link : [**Getting Started with REST - Register your client application with Azure AD**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#register-your-client-application-with-azure-ad).

> Most Azure services (such as [Azure Resource Manager providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-supported-services) and the classic deployment model) require your client code to authenticate with valid credentials before you can call the service's API. Authentication is coordinated between the various actors by Azure AD, and provides your client with an [access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/developer-glossary#access-token) as proof of the authentication. The token is then sent to the Azure service in the HTTP Authorization header of subsequent REST API requests. The token's [claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/developer-glossary#claim) also provide information to the service, allowing it to validate the client and perform any required authorization.